# t:saveState to save state of Managed Bean with RequestScope - State for Pagination System

Tags: java, jsf-2, tomahawk, savestate

I am trying to work with tomahawk-saveState, but it is simply not working. I inserted the following code to my xhtml file (JSF2.0):

```
 <t:saveState value="#{managedBean1}"/>
```

Using a managed bean like this one:

```
 @ManagedBean
 @RequestScoped
 public class ManagedBean1 implements Serializable {...}
```

I am tying to use this with a pagination system, so it can keep the state of the page number during the navigation on that page. Now, when I open the page then the **pagination system is null and creates itself (good)**, but then I refresh the page (F5) or click on next page and the **pagination system is null again and the bean creates it again**. So, as you can see the pagination does not work because it cannot keep the state, so what could I be doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.